# I need to horizontally scroll to a div id using React.JS ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

```
scrollFunc()
{    
     document.getElementById("myID").scrollIntoView({"block":"center"})    
}
```

I tried scrollIntoView({"block":"center"}) works perfect in chrome but has issues on Internet Explorer !

Answer (score 5):

scrollIntoView has partial support in IE/Edge.

`scrollIntoView({"block":"center"})` is not supported by IE/Edge

---

- You have the option `scrollIntoView(true)` 
  which corresponds to

`scrollIntoView({block: "start", inline: "nearest"})`

- You have the option `scrollIntoView(false)` 
  which corresponds to

`scrollIntoView({block: "end", inline: "nearest"})`

---

I would recommend using other API or approach if you need `{"block":"center"}`.

Read more about it here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView
https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll

Comment: Can you give an alternative API ?

Comment: @shubhampandey I would recommend look into **scrollTo**
Something like
`var bcr = element.getBoundingClientRect();
window.scrollTo(bcr.left - bcr.width/2, bcr.top - bcr.height/2);`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,

To get the position of any element in page, you can use 'getBoundingClientRect' method like this, and window.scrollTo() to scroll to that particular location.

`var htmlElement = document.getElementById('container');
 var elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect()
 window.scrollTo(elementPosition.left, 0)`

Also refer this link for more learning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Not Working as expected !

Comment: for horizontal scrolling you need to give only the x-coordindate value.  Give left value of the element to it.  I have edited the code accordingly

Comment: Did u try debugging..because it has support for IE too